# Get the Current Date from Internet GMT+6

Tags: java, android

I want to Get the current Date from internet.
When I will open my app it will compare the mobile date with Internet date. If Both are same app will starts else show an alertDialouge.

Help me to solve this. Don't Refer to others questions.  I have seen many questions in SoF but I didn't get any answer which is related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

[Actual Answer taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36997897/5602752)

You may use this api provided by http://www.geonames.org/login. it's gives you a real time. example of rest api like below

http://api.geonames.org/timezoneJSON?lat=51.5034070&lng=-0.1275920&username=your_user_name